# pusher authenticating java client with laravel server

Tags: java, laravel, pusher

can you please help me,
I'm working on an realtime application using java for client side and laravel for the server side.
I konw that clients need to be authenticated in odrer to use private-channel, I've found something like this :

```
final HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("http://www.example.com/private_auth.php");
final PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer);
```

but I don't know how to authenticate them in the server side ?

What should the destination of the authentication request be ?